# updatepanel databind not refreshing data until about 10 seconds after data actually updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, updatepanel

I'm working with a GridView inside an UpdatePanel. The after updating the data, clicking a refresh button tied to a DataBind() won't change anything on the page until at least 10 seconds after the data has been updated. Here is the relevant code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" >

            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">  
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh"  CausesValidation="False" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="btnRefresh_OnClick" /> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True"
                            DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="sqldatasource" CssClass="table table-responsive table-hover"
                            OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound"
                            OnRowCommand="GridView1_OnRowCommand"
                            >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Open" />
                                <!-- columns -->
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the code behind:

```
    protected void btnRefresh_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I am using the same type of setup on another page without using the UpdateMode or Triggers and that has no problem data binding, but this will not.

Comment: can we see `sqldatasource`?

Comment: That was it. I'm porting the application, and the previous application had enabled caching on the data source. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for posterity. The SQL Data Source had caching enabled, so I removed that and databind works as expected without delay.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlInProgress" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AppConnectionString %>" EnableCaching="true"  CacheDuration="30"
                       SelectCommand =" SELECT [Order].[id] as id, [Checker], [InternalComments], [CompanyName], [ProdLine], [ProductName],[Due], [Fulfillment], [FulfillmentX], [QA],  [QAX], FROM [Order], [Companies] where [Order].[CompanyName] = [Companies].[CompanyName] and [stage] = 'In progress' order by Due" />
```